Trying to access a .gz file inside a .zip file through Python
I have a .zip file with a large amount of .gz files, which I need to process. I want to open the .zip, which I can easily do through this code:
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "r")
for gzfile in zf.filelist:
    with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=zf.open(gzfile.filename, "r"), mode="r") as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, compression="gzip", sep=";")

However, this results in NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported, which is caused by the zf.open(gzfile). The existing StackOverflow tickets related to this, do not tackle this problem.

zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "rb") results in ValueError: ZipFile requires mode 'r', 'w', 'x', or 'a' and zf.open(gzfile.filename, "rb") results in ValueError: open() requires mode "r" or "w"

Firstly, you should call the namelist method of a ZipFile to retrieve a list of member names.
Secondly, you need only either gzip.GzipFile or pd.read_csv with the compression="gzip" option to decompression the file as gzip. Using both will result in pd.read_csv trying to decompress plain file as gzip, resulting in the said error.
Finally, it is better to use zipfile.ZipFile as a context manager so that it closes the file for you after use.
So do either:
with zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "r") as zf:
    for gzfile in zf.filelist:
        with zf.open(gzfile.filename, "r") as f:
            df = pd.read_csv(f, compression="gzip", sep=";")

or:
with zipfile.ZipFile("file.zip", "r") as zf:
    for gzfile in zf.filelist:
        with zf.open(gzfile.filename, "r") as gzip_file:
            with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzip_file, "r"), mode="r") as f:
                df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";")


Both will still result in the NotImplementedError: That compression method is not supported.  The problem is caused by zf.open(gzfile.filename, "r"), which is not supported by zipfile for .gz files.
